# Uploadify : IO error and HTTP error when uploading big file

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload big files upto 60MB.

I am getting HTTP error while uploading 17MB file after uploading complete and processing while getting IO error in between uploading is in progress with 58 MB file.

what could be the issue?

Comment: Can you specify the HTTP error and the IO error ?

Comment: IO error #2038 and HTTP error 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to increase the file upload limits add these lines on your `.htaccess` file

Change values according to your need. If it does't change contact to your service provider to increase upload limits.

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 100
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [why-does-uploadify-stop-when-trying-to-upload-large-files](http://www.uploadify.com/faqs/why-does-uploadify-stop-when-trying-to-upload-large-files/).

Comment: yes. I have checked it and set all of them to 1g. and works with same configuration on local well.

Comment: @user985361 Have you tested in some other browser?

Comment: Yes. I have tried on FF and Chrome. both are giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the HTTP error and the IO error ?

By default, PHP only accept max 2mb files upload. Check on your php.ini :

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Comment: yes. I have checked it and set all of them to 1g. and works with same configuration on local well.